# Objective C - TextView Number of Lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview

I have a problem.
I would like to know how I can get the exact number of WRITTEN lines of a text in a text view .
I do not want the number of lines possible, but those that have been used and filled by characters.

For example:

[image: In this case the result is 2.]
[image: In this case the result is 3.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try going something along the lines of

```
[textField sizeToFit]; //Get the minimum height and width for the text
NSInteger numLines = textField.frame.size.height / textField.font.lineHieght
```

However I haven't tried it myself

Comment: You might find this is not entirely accurate when a larger number of lines is involved. In particular you could have problems on an iPhone 6+ - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487402/189804 - sizeToFit appears to work differently!