# Dynamically adjust the height of the UITextView depending on its content?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have an `UITextView` that loads different text depending on the route the user has taken in order to get to the view with the text on it.

How do I dynamically adjust the height of the `UITextView` depending on its content using Swift?

Comment: I saw that one however I'm asking specifically with reference to Swift :)

Comment: Go through the answers for that question, you will see a swift solution] for the same :)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28916825/3950397

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setup your constraints so that the edges are pinned but allow the text view to grow vertically. Then set a height constraint (the value doesn't matter here). Create an `@IBOutlet` for the `UITextView` and the height constraint. Then we can dynamically change the height in code:

```
class ViewControler: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        let sizeToFitIn = CGSizeMake(self.textView.bounds.size.width, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
        let newSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(sizeToFitIn)
        self.textViewHeight.constant = newSize.height
    }

}
```

Comment: what if text view is located in a tableview cell?