# UITextView height doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift, size, uitextview

`UITextView` height doesn't work on iPhone when I use dynamic content from `UITextViewCell`. On any iPad it works is well. I already read it([How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)) but it didn't help me.

My code is below

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! {
    didSet {
        textView?.text = textOfText
        self.textView.delegate = self
        self.textView.editable = false
        self.textView.scrollEnabled = false
    }
}

 @IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint! {
        didSet {
            self.textViewHeight.constant = self.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.textView.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max)).height
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED**
That is how same text is look on iPhone and iPad.
[image]
[image]

**UPDATED 2**
I made following code

```
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! {
    didSet {
        textView?.text = textOfText
        self.textView.delegate = self
        self.textView.editable = false
        self.textView.scrollEnabled = false
        var frame: CGRect!
        frame = textView.frame
        frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height
        textView.frame = frame
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe the troubleshooting you've done? Are all of your methods called as expected? What value do you expect to be assigned to `textViewHeight.constant`? What value is actually assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the work `UITextView height`. I deleted `@IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!` and it works for me. My UITextView code is look as

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! {
    didSet {
        textView?.text = textOfText
        textView.delegate = self
        var frame: CGRect!
        frame = textView.frame
        frame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height
        self.textView.frame = frame

    }
}
```