# How to find AutoGrowing textview Height Dynamically in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am trying to get `autoGrowing` textview height dynamically, i.e  I mean text data is coming from services for each time when we loading the app.

And my main requirement is I want to find `textview` exact `height` because of sometimes `textview` data is increasing sometimes decreasing according to data which comes from services.

That's what I want to find and I don't want to resize `textview` because I have already that technique.

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content

Comment: i want textview height,i don't want resize textview because i have already that texhnique