# Moving the textView content to the top when editing

Tags: swift, resize, uitextview

I have a UITextView in my ViewController. I resize programmatically his height to the content by this code (found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)) :

```
let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
var newFrame = textView.frame
newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
textView.frame = newFrame
```

The problem is : when the user edits the TextView, I would like the text to move to the top, instead of moving to the bottom. Anyone could help me please ?

An example : 
[image]