# Dynamic height for textview in ios?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have added a `UITextView` inside a `UIView`. `UIView` has some height depending upon screen sizes. `UITextView` can have more or less text. So I want to make the height of `UITextView` dynamic so if text is more then it should have more height but it should be less than the height of main view . If text is less then it should have less height.

Comment: dont you want the textview to scroll ?

Comment: No i don't want to scroll

Comment: r u using storyboard ?

Comment: r u used autolayout or autoresizing in your project

Comment: I am using story board & autolayout

Comment: @deepakkumar hope this will work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Size a UITextView to its content programmatically:

```
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [textView setDelegate:self];
    [textView setText:@"your long text"];
    [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];

    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `textview` to display multilines of text with scrolling disabled, It is nothing more than a `UILabel`. I suggest you to use `UILabel` for the purpose.

In the storyboard, set the constraints as follows:

[image]

and set the line break as word wrap:
[image]

Comment: please note that constraint values are given as per my need. You can modify them as per your need

Comment: for text wrap around images i am using textview as label

Comment: you can even wrap the text in uilabel, the only difference is labels are read only and text views are editable.

Comment: I have used beizer path to set the text wrap.which is not possible using label

Comment: try this with text view giving the same constraints, see if it works or not. I think this set of constraints shold work on text view too. Make sure your textview is not scrollable .

Answer (score 0):

Same as the first answer, but in Swift 4:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let textView = UITextView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 40, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))
textView.delegate = self as? UITextViewDelegate
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
view.addSubview(textView)

let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
let newSize: CGSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
var newFrame = textView.frame
newFrame.size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(fmaxf(Float(newSize.width), Float(fixedWidth))), height: newSize.height)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this

```
-(void)dynamicTextSize{
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 200, 30)];
textView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:textView];

NSString *string  = @"This is pour text.a hjajksdkja kajhdsjk akjdhs jakhd skjahs ajkdhsjkad hskja akjdhs ajkhdjskar";
textView.text = string;

//UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0f];
NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:textView.font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];

textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

CGRect frame  = [textView.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, 10000) options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attrDict context:nil];

CGRect mFrame = textView.frame;
mFrame.size.width = frame.size.width;
mFrame.size.height = frame.size.height;
textView.frame = mFrame;

//NSLog(@"frame2:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(textView.frame));
}
```

Comment: what is **attrdict**?

Comment: what to do with **size**.Where to set it?

Comment: i have a little change of  return "CGRect frame =..."

Comment: so i set the frame again as you defined here