# UITextView dynamic sizing is making the textView too tall

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content) link to resize a textView dynamically. However, I implement it into a function and it return a height of 238. Using the heirarchy viewer I can see my textView is indeed 238, but there is a ton of empty space as 238 is way taller than needed. Can anyone figure out why `textView.sizeThatFits:` would give me this kind of error? Here is my code.

```
func heightOfTextFieldForMessage(message : String) -> CGFloat {
    let horizontalMargin = CGFloat(194)

    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.text = message
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)

    //This width is same as in heirachy viewer, horizontalMargin is a constant distance the textView is from edges of the screen.
    let fixedWidth = self.view.frame.width - horizontalMargin
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))


    let height = newSize.height
    print(height)
    return height
}
```

Is it possibly because my font is smaller than the default font? I tried changing the `textView`'s font size before resizing but it seems like like the height does change based on what I set the font to.

The Text View bottom constraint is tied to the top of the icon so as you can see the textView is way taller than needed.

[image]

Comment: did you pass the trimmed text to heightOfTextFieldForMessage ?

Comment: sizeThatFits is a calculation method ,it will change when the text attribute change

Comment: @WilsonXJ I know but the actual textView uses the same font/text attributes so shouldn't it return a height that is still good for my textView and not one that is way taller?

Comment: and @ArunGJ I just pass the string going into the textField. I'll post a screenshot so you guys can see the text.

Comment: @WilsonXJ I found the solution and it was a problem with the textView's font with calculation not matching the textViews font being used. I upvoted your comment but if you make an answer I'll accept it since your comment was the most valuable in helping me figure out my problem.

Comment: It's a pleasure to help you.

Comment: Either OP or @WilsonXJ should provide and accept an answer for this question.