# How to create UITableViewCell with dynamic cell height based on its content

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7

I was trying to explore the new feature of dynamic cell height using auto layout, introduced in Xcode 7 using [this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift). I have one UITableViewCell like this below

[image: Title Label with image view and its description(in UITextView) below]

I want cell to adjust its size automatically based on the content in textView and size of image. I set all constraint and given `estimatedRowHeight` and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`  as tableview row height. But when i run the app i'm not able to see the UITextView below. Which means that cell height is not getting adjusted dynamically. Do i need to set the cell height programmatically or still i can do it using Auto Layout.

Comment: if you have textview is self scrollable then why you need to increase height of tableview dynamically , and make sure your cell content view is fixed from 4 sides needed for automatic dimensions

Comment: Does your app supports iOS 9 or above? This only supports iOS 9 and above.If you are running in below iOS 9 version then it won't work

Comment: This may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content

Answer (score 2):

For TextView, it must not be scrollable.

Also,  Your constraints are should be provided in such a way that, TableViewCell should get height automatically(there must be vertical spacing constraints between each component, Height of the each component must be there(it may be explicit of implicit height, but it must need to have height)).

Also, estimatedHeight you are providing must be near to actual average height.

If your tableViewCell is getting above things, then and then only it will get dynamic height based on its content.