# Change position of sub view under a text view based on the text views content swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitextview

How could I️ achieve a similar effect to Twitter’s tweet view, where the location label position changes based on how much text is inputted. For instance [image: No text]

When there’s no text, the location label is right under the text view but when text is inputted, the label changes its position: 
[image: text added]

How could I️ achieve a similar effect in swift?

Comment: Note that they are most likely using a custom subclass of UITextView, not UITextField, as UITextField is single line while UITextView supports multi-line.

Comment: I️ just fixed that in the question

Comment: Could you set the locations label to the bottom of the label and everytime a line is filled increase the height of the label

Comment: A Mix of Autolayout, with the location label's topAnchor fixed to the textView's bottomAnchor; and a fixed heightAnchor. While making sure the textView expands on line count increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content) regarding fitting a UITextView to the content of its text.

In the UITextView shouldChangeTextInRange delegate call, update the frame of the UITextView to fit the text. Then update your location labels frame relative to this new UITextView frame.