# UIView setting constraints

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble creating a `UIView` instance programmatically. I have a function that returns the view so that I can use it in an `NSAttachment` inside a `UITextView`.

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image] 
This is what I am getting in the simulator:
[image]

**Code Below:**

```
let fullView = UIView()
    let firstButton = UIButton()
    let secondButton = UIButton()
    let thirdTextView = UITextView()

    fullView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textView.frame.width, height: 90)
    fullView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.82, green:0.83, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0)

    firstButton.setTitle(text1, for: .normal)
    firstButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    firstButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
    firstButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left

    secondButton.setTitle("Button2", for: .normal)
    secondButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    secondButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
    secondButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right

    thirdTextView.text = text2

    let descriptionBarStackView = UIStackView()
    descriptionBarStackView.axis = .horizontal
    descriptionBarStackView.alignment = .fill 
    descriptionBarStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally 

    descriptionBarStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstButton)
    descriptionBarStackView.addArrangedSubview(secondButton)

    let viewWithStackViews = UIStackView()
    viewWithStackViews.axis = .vertical
    viewWithStackViews.alignment = .fill // .leading .firstBaseline .center .trailing .lastBaseline
    viewWithStackViews.distribution = .fillEqually
    viewWithStackViews.addArrangedSubview(descriptionBarStackView)
    viewWithStackViews.addArrangedSubview(thirdTextView)


    fullView.addSubview(viewWithStackViews)

    descriptionBarStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    thirdTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewWithStackViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    viewWithStackViews.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
    viewWithStackViews.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
    viewWithStackViews.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
    viewWithStackViews.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
    ])
```

Edit: [image]

Comment: You need set trailingAnchor constant -5 instead of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Check this updated method

```
func customView(){

let fullView = UIView()
let firstButton = UIButton()
let secondButton = UIButton()
let thirdTextView = UITextView()

fullView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mainView.frame.width, height: mainView.frame.height)
fullView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.82, green:0.83, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0)

firstButton.setTitle("Button1", for: .normal)
firstButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
firstButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
firstButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
firstButton.backgroundColor = .clear

secondButton.setTitle("Button2", for: .normal)
secondButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
secondButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
secondButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
secondButton.backgroundColor = .clear

thirdTextView.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
thirdTextView.backgroundColor = .clear

let descriptionBarStackView = UIStackView()
descriptionBarStackView.axis = .horizontal
descriptionBarStackView.alignment = .fill
descriptionBarStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
descriptionBarStackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
descriptionBarStackView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5)

descriptionBarStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstButton)
descriptionBarStackView.addArrangedSubview(secondButton)

let viewWithStackViews = UIStackView()
viewWithStackViews.axis = .vertical
viewWithStackViews.alignment = .fill // .leading .firstBaseline .center .trailing .lastBaseline
viewWithStackViews.distribution = .fill
viewWithStackViews.addArrangedSubview(descriptionBarStackView)
viewWithStackViews.addArrangedSubview(thirdTextView)

fullView.addSubview(viewWithStackViews)

descriptionBarStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
thirdTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
viewWithStackViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint(item: descriptionBarStackView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    viewWithStackViews.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
    viewWithStackViews.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    viewWithStackViews.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
    viewWithStackViews.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
    ])

fullView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
mainView.addSubview(fullView)
```

}

> here i have listed changes

- mainView.frame.height full height based on main text view
- firstButton.backgroundColor = .clear
- secondButton.backgroundColor = .clear
- thirdTextView.backgroundColor = .clear
- margin for button 
  descriptionBarStackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
  descriptionBarStackView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5)
- NSLayoutConstraint constraint zero to all in full view
- fullView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

> thats it here is result..
>   [image]

Comment: Thanks for that! 3 questions. 1. I am wanting the buttons height to not grow, so it would always be fixed and not create space. 2. I need the views height to grow dependant on how much text is provided in thirdTextView.text 3. I need the width to be the width of the textView container it seems mainView.frame.width is making it too wide...

Comment: @a.wip for your first que answer is descriptionBarStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint(item: descriptionBarStackView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30).isActive = true
viewWithStackViews.distribution = .fill

for second que set height depend on text as u want
for third que set width from textview as u set

Comment: Okay, added those into my code. I am still having trouble with the width, I have added an edit above. It still seems to be cutting off.

Comment: okay, have u set margin and set constraint to zero for viewWithStackViews ?

Comment: I am using your code from the comment and function.  What am I missing?

Comment: descriptionBarStackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
descriptionBarStackView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5)

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    viewWithStackViews.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
    viewWithStackViews.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    viewWithStackViews.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
    viewWithStackViews.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
    ])

should be zero

Comment: Okay, it seems something is wrong with my width because if I set it manually it's working fine...

Comment: It's still not working properly. It's only working with textView.frame.width - 10 Is there an extra 10 pixels somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to preserve your layout structure
[image]

```
class VisualTestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let fullView = UIView()
        fullView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.82, green:0.83, blue:0.85, alpha:1.0)
        fullView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let firstButton = UIButton()
        firstButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let secondButton = UIButton()
        secondButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let thirdTextView = UITextView()
        thirdTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false



        thirdTextView.text = "lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum"

        let text1 = "Button1"
        firstButton.setTitle(text1, for: .normal)
        firstButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        firstButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
        firstButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left


        secondButton.setTitle("Button2", for: .normal)
        secondButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        secondButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
        secondButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right


        let descriptionBarStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [firstButton, UIView() ,secondButton])
        descriptionBarStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        descriptionBarStackView.axis = .horizontal
        descriptionBarStackView.alignment = .center

        let viewWithStackViews = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [descriptionBarStackView, thirdTextView])
        viewWithStackViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewWithStackViews.axis = .vertical
        viewWithStackViews.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        viewWithStackViews.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true

        fullView.addSubview(viewWithStackViews)


        fullView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWithStackViews.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        fullView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWithStackViews.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        fullView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWithStackViews.topAnchor).isActive = true
        fullView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWithStackViews.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        view.addSubview(fullView)
        fullView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        fullView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        fullView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        thirdTextView.isScrollEnabled = false

        thirdTextView.backgroundColor = .clear
    }


}
```

Comment: How can I make view get larger dependant on how much text is in thirdTextView?

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content

Comment: That's not working for me... Can I somehow allow it to just dynamically get larger dependant on size of thirdTextView? Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You are setting
`viewWithStackViews.distribution = .fillEqually`

Because of `.fillEqually` the `StackView` will allocate equal height to the subviews. Thats why you are seeing buttons in half of `viewWithStackViews` and `thirdTextView` in remaining half.
So change it to: 
`viewWithStackViews.distribution = .fillProportionally`

One more thing: your `thirdTextView` is not getting its height according to its content. 
Try this to allow you `thirdTextView` to get height automatically. In case the text might be too long, set `scrolledEnabled` to true and set height contraint for the textView.

`thirdTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
  thirdTextView.sizeToFit()
  thirdTextView.scrollEnabled = false`