# How to get Editor in Xamarin Forms iOS to auto resize and be scrollable with its content?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, scrollview, editor

I have a **ScrollView** with an **Editor** content inside.

I'm creating a custom Editor which resizes dependant on text inside it.

```
        <ScrollView x:Name="sv" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Both"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
            <local:EditorEx x:Name="ed" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        </ScrollView>
```

I've successfully managed to get the editor to dynamically resize the editor based on this code placed in the renderer:

[How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)

```
      void Init()
        {
            //needed for below code to work
        Control.ScrollEnabled = false;
        }

        private void Control_Changed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            CGSize newSize = Control.SizeThatFits(new CGSize(nfloat.MaxValue, nfloat.MaxValue));
            CGRect newFrame = Control.Frame;
            newFrame.Size = new CGSize(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);
            //Control.Frame = newFrame;
  
            //this is the xamarin Editor control
            editor.WidthRequest = newSize.Width;
            editor.HeightRequest = newSize.Height;
        }
```

However, the ScrollView does not dynamically re-adjust according to the new editor size and hence I can't scroll to the newly added text.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: As you've seen, the ScrollView doesn't know that it should resize when the Entry content resizes. You'll have to manually set its WidthRequest and HeightRequest. Use MessagingCenter. In your custom control, Publish a message describing the editor size change. In your page that contains `sv`, Subscribe to that message, set sv.WidthRequest etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. sv.WidthRequest however will refer to the **visible** width, not the **virtual** width, which is what I need. The only reference within sv to the virtual size is **ContentSize** which is a readonly property.

Comment: You are right; I was thinking about it wrong. Try `sv.ForceLayout();`

Comment: Looks like it's working. If you want to write an answer to this I will up-vote it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a layout to recalculate its display, after a programmatic change that affects it, try `ForceLayout`:

```cs
sv.ForceLayout();
```

In most cases this happens automatically, but ScrollView does not realize that a change to its contents may require this.